# QGIS Spatial Join Includes Records From Features Just Outside Polygon

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I am using QGIS to do spatial joins between UK parliamentary constituency boundaries and subsidy amounts associated with areas defined by boundaries in a separate layer. The idea is to find the subsidy amounts for the parliamentary constituencies. What I am finding is that the join is including areas that appear on screen to be outside the constituency boundary, but with part of the boundary very close to the constituency boundary. My subsidy data is for England only, but the join is assigning subsidies in English constituencies to the neighbouring Welsh constituencies.

Is this a common problem? What is the likely cause? How can it be dealt with? Any help very welcome.

Comment: Are both layers using the same projection? Is it the same one as the display?

Comment: Yes. Everything is using EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid.

Comment: what spatial predicate are you using, is it "intersects"? Do the two polygon layers have identical polygons, but only one has the data you need?